# What would be the java regular expression for the following?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that can contain characters like abc+123def or abc-123def or only abc123def. What would be the regular expression to extract only the numbers and the signs with them ?For e.g. +123 or -123 or 123 ... ?

Answer (score 2):

here is the regular expression I think you're looking for.

```
"[-\+]?\d+"
```

be careful, you might have to escape the `'` key

Comment: What's the `@` intended to be?

Comment: @GregHewgill  It's to make the string literal, This is based on my c# understanding of regex where you have to escape your escape key

Comment: Well, that's C#, but this is a Java question. Java doesn't use `@` for strings.

Comment: Also, this won't match `abc123def`.

Answer (score 1):

```
([+-]?[0-9]+)
```

`[+-]?` says give me zero or one sign
`[0-9]+` give me at least 1 digit

Answer (score 0):

If the number always immediately follows the sign: `[+-]?\d+`.

Comment: Typo. Meant to put `?` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 0):

use this regular expression `[+-]?\d+`

Comment: This won't match `abc123def`.